# Overload stream operator for template type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I would like to print a class instance, it looks like not a template type, but it's data pointer can be used to store multiple data(uchar/int/float), thus I came up with:

- overload the stream operator, call the templated version
- write the templated version of the stream operator

However it just failed to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;

using uchar = unsigned char;

enum class ArrayType
{
    UCHAR = 1,
    INT = 3,
    FLOAT = 4,
};

class MagicArray
{
public:
    Ptr<uchar[]> data;
    ArrayType type;
    int bytes;

public:
    MagicArray()
        : bytes(0), type(ArrayType::UCHAR), data(nullptr)
    {}

    MagicArray(int _bytes, ArrayType _type)
        : bytes(_bytes), type(_type), data(new uchar[_bytes])
    {
    }

public:
    int len() const {
        if (type == ArrayType::UCHAR)
        {
            return bytes;
        }
        else if (type == ArrayType::INT)
        {
            return bytes / sizeof(int);
        }
        else if (type == ArrayType::FLOAT)
        {
            return bytes / sizeof(float);
        }
        return -1; // not supported
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MagicArray& arr)
{
    os << ">>> the general one";
    T* data = arr.data;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.len(); i++)
    {
        os << data[i] << ", ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MagicArray& arr)
{
    switch(arr.type)
    {
        case ArrayType::UCHAR:
            return std::operator<<<uchar>(std::cout, arr);  // !! this line, failed to compile
        case ArrayType::INT:
            return std::operator<<<int>(std::cout, arr);  // !! this line, failed to compile
        case ArrayType::FLOAT:
            return std::operator<<<float>(std::cout, arr);  // !! this line, failed to compile
    }
}

int main()
{
    MagicArray arr1(16, ArrayType::UCHAR);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.len(); i++)
    {
        arr1.data[i] = i;
    }

    MagicArray arr2(16, ArrayType::INT);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.len(); i++)
    {
        arr2.data[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << arr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr2 << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Note: the class `MagicArray`, for this question, I would not like to change it to a template type.

**Question: How can I print instance of MagicArray type correctly according to their data pointer actual type, base on the above code?**

===
update

What I thought is too simple.
1). Print uchar types would cause not visible characters.
2). I should explicitly call the `operator<<`.

Now the solution code would be like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MagicArray& arr)
{
    os << ">>> operator<T> << () ";
    T* data = (T*)arr.data.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.len(); i++)
    {
        os << data[i] << ", ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
    return os;
}

template<>
std::ostream& operator << <uchar> (std::ostream& os, const MagicArray& arr)
{
    os << ">>> operator<uchar> << () ";
    uchar* data = (uchar*)arr.data.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.len(); i++)
    {
        os << (int)(data[i]) << ", ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MagicArray& arr)
{
    switch(arr.type)
    {
        case ArrayType::UCHAR:
            return operator<< <uchar>(std::cout, arr);
        case ArrayType::INT:
            return operator<< <int>(std::cout, arr);
        case ArrayType::FLOAT:
            return operator<< <float>(std::cout, arr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    MagicArray arr1(16, ArrayType::UCHAR);
    uchar* ptr1 = (uchar*)arr1.data.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.len(); i++)
    {
        ptr1[i] = i+100;
    }

    MagicArray arr2(16, ArrayType::INT);
    int* ptr2 = (int*)arr2.data.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.len(); i++)
    {
        ptr2[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << arr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the compiler error and desired output

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Well...I think I have found the solution, updated in the description, thus I would not paste the error..

Comment: if you found a solution you should rather post it as an answer. After your edit the question is even less clear.

Comment: in other words, what is the question now?

Comment: The *initial* error was in having the `std::` namespace prefix on the `operator<<` calls. But then, with that resolved, there was also a problem in trying to implicitly convert a `shared_ptr` to a `T*`.